# Elastic search - Search by alphabet characters A-Z

Tags: elasticsearch, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I would like to ask how to filter specific data with elastic search by simple 1 character **A-Z**

so.. for example i got data

- Orange
- Apple
- Ancient
- Axe

I would like to get all results which start(not contains) with character for example **"A"**. So results is

- Apple
- Ancient
- Axe

I found here that i should create new analyzer analyzer_startswith and set up like this. What am doing wrong? Now im getting **0 results**

**Elastica .yml config**

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: noImportantInfo
    indexes:
        bundleName:
            client: default
            finder: ~
            settings:
                index:
                    analysis:
                        analyzer:
                            analyzer_startswith:
                                type: custom
                                tokenizer: keyword
                                filter:
                                    - lowercase
            types:
                content:
                    properties:
                        id:
                            type: integer
                        elasticaPriority:
                            type: integer
                        title:
                            type: string
                            analyzer: another_custom_analyzer
                            fields:
                                raw:
                                    type: string
                                    index: not_analyzed
                        title_ngram:
                            type: string
                            analyzer: analyzer_startswith
                            property_path: title
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Prefix query for this see here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-prefix-query.html :

```
GET /_search
{ "query": {
    "prefix" : { "user" : "ki" }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i used prefix and its working.

I set index to not_analyzed and used Prefix to find a first character in string.

```
title_ngram:
   type: string
   property_path: title
   index: not_analyzed
```

Is there any other way how to apply a standard search for my **"title_ngram"** now? Because i would like to search by single 1 character and also full text search in **"title_ngram"**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
GET /content/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": "A"
        }
    },
    "sort": "title.raw"
}
```

For more information refer below link
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-fields.html